# Not getting the right result when using ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, local

When I ran the code, I'm expecting the result to show

```
Thread-0 - hello-0
Thread-1 - hello-1
```

However, the first thread seems to be returning null. Where am I going wrong here?

```
public class MyThreadLocal extends Thread {

private static final ThreadLocal<String> testId = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();


public MyThreadLocal(String testId) {
    this.testId.set(testId);
}

public void run() {
    int loop = 10;

    for (int i=0;i<loop;i++) {
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" - "+testId.get());
        try {this.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MyThreadLocal("hello-0").start();
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    new MyThreadLocal("hello-1").start();
}
}
```

output is

```
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
Thread-0 - null
Thread-1 - hello-0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the values on the main thread (before you start the other threads) and you except them to be visible on Thread-0 and Thread-1.

Try this:

```
package ro.derbederos.hlfe.impl.util;

public class MyThreadLocal extends Thread {

private static final ThreadLocal<String> testId = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();

String testIdString;

public MyThreadLocal(String testId) {
this.testIdString = testId;
}

public void run() {
    int loop = 10;
    testId.set(testIdString);


    for (int i=0;i<loop;i++) {
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" - "+testId.get());
        try {this.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MyThreadLocal("hello-0").start();
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    new MyThreadLocal("hello-1").start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new MyThreadLocal("hello-0") sets ThreadLocal before you start the thread, that is in the main thread, not in hello-0 thread, this is why its ThredLocal value = null. new MyThreadLocal("hello-1") acts in the same manner, the difference in output is because you use InheritableThreadLocal, so the second thread inherited the thread local from main.